# How to get value of key in Python Blackjack game

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random, blackjack

I just started a blackjack game project. So far, i've created cards and hand creator funtion. As you can see from my code down below, i pick my hand through pick() function and i get the keys of the rank dictionary.

```
rank={'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,
   'K':10,'Q':10,'A':1}
your_hand=[]
opponent_hand=[]
def pick():    
    your_hand =  random.sample(list(rank),2) 
    opponent_hand = random.sample(list(rank),2) 
    print(your_hand[values])
    print(opponent_hand)
def count():
    pass
```

I was wondering is this code getting their values and if not, how can i get their values? Also is this a good approach for coding a blackjack game.

Comment: A comment about BlackJack rules: the ace value is 11 by default. From [wikipedia BlackJack page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack#Card_counting):  _A hand with an ace valued as 11 is called "soft", meaning that the hand will not bust by taking an additional card. The value of the ace will become one to prevent the hand from exceeding 21. Otherwise, the hand is called "hard"._

Comment: one problem i see is that there can be a game where the two players both have the same card. to solve this i suggest deleting the cards the first player received from **ramk** before picking the cards for the second player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `values` isn't connected to anything, so you'll get a `NameError` when you try to reference it.

The lists `your_hand` and `opponent_hand` contain lists of strings (keys in `rank`).  To convert those into the values from `rank`, you need to use the keys to do lookups, e.g.:

```
your_hand_values = [rank[card] for card in your_hand]
```

which will give you a list of `int`s.  If you want to get the sum, you could use `sum`:

```
your_hand_total = sum(rank[card] for card in your_hand)
```

On to the larger question, one problem with this approach is that it's not possible for a hand to have more than one card with the same rank, where a real deck of cards has 4 suits.

Since building a blackjack game is a pretty common beginner coding problem I keep this post bookmarked for when someone asks how I'd do it.  :)  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234880/blackjack-21-in-python3/234890#234890

Answer (score 0):

Passing a dict to list() returns a list of the *keys*. So your_hand is a list, containing keys to the rank dictionary. To get the corresponding *values*:

```
your_hand_values = [rank[card] for card in your_hand]
```

You might consider storing both the card and it's value in the your_hand list from the beginning, like this :

```
your_hand =  [(card, value) for card, value in random.sample(rank.items(), 2)]
```

(As a side note, this is a project crying out for an OOP approach. Just my 2 cents.)